# can not upload a jupytor notebook into the localhost

Tags: python, jupyter

I can't upload this file: text-mining-lab.ipynb

After 2 minutes the status of the notebook is still "uploading"!

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out, in the new version of anaconda, "-" is not accepted! I changed it to "_" then the file uploaded immediately:

```
text_mining_lab.ipynb
```